# Unable to find functions for BSOD in windows

Tags: windows, crash, windbg

In Linux system, It has a **kernel_panic** function responsible for the OS crash. Suppose there is a similar function in Windows 10, I want to locate its symbol.

I want my analysis tool to be able to catch system crash in the image by locating its memory location. I'm trying to target the function with the same functionality in Windows through debugging. For example, there are some very often BSODs like **IRQL_NOT_LESS_EQUAL** and **PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA**. Errors in **tcpip.sys** can cause these crashes.

I want to track the function by reviewing the call stack after manually triggering a system crash. Since I'm in the kernel mode, I'm unable to use **.call** command in windbg. Like the output below, the page-related problem is probably in **nt** kernel. Thus, I tried to replace the RIP's value with the functions' addresses. None of them worked. Based on my intention and approach, what might be the problem?

```
1: kd> x *!*page*fault*
fffff800`3e96ea44 nt!MiResolvePageFileFault (void)
fffff800`3e9268d0 nt!MiInitializePageFaultPacket (void)
fffff800`3e92e57c nt!PfSnLogPageFaultCommon (void)
fffff800`3eb35434 nt!EtwpCoverageSamplerPageFault (EtwpCoverageSamplerPageFault)
fffff800`3e8733b4 nt!PfSnLogPageFault (PfSnLogPageFault)
fffff800`3e865ab0 nt!xHalIommuServicePageFault (xHalIommuServicePageFault)
fffff800`3e9e0880 nt!KiPageFault (KiPageFault)
fffff800`3eb4c800 nt!KiPageFaultShadow (KiPageFaultShadow)
fffff800`3eb2dbf4 nt!EtwTracePageFault (EtwTracePageFault)
fffff800`3eb3c000 nt!ExpSvmServicePageFault (ExpSvmServicePageFault)
fffff800`3ead9bf8 nt!MiLargePageFault (MiLargePageFault)
fffff800`3f2cd9c0 hal!IvtGetPageFault (IvtGetPageFault)
fffff800`3f2d0070 hal!HsaDismissPageFault (HsaDismissPageFault)
fffff800`3f2c9940 hal!IommupHvDismissPageFault (IommupHvDismissPageFault)
fffff800`3f2ccfe0 hal!IvtDismissPageFault (IvtDismissPageFault)
fffff800`3f2d0a60 hal!HsaGetPageFault (HsaGetPageFault)
fffff800`3f31bf80 hal!HalpBlkPageFault (HalpBlkPageFault)
fffff800`3f2c9a80 hal!IommupHvGetPageFault (IommupHvGetPageFault)
fffff802`42434fb8 Wof!g_PagesFaultedOnAgain = <no type information>
fffff802`4446916c dxgmms2!VIDMM_GLOBAL::PageInFaultedAllocation (void)
fffff802`4449b5ec dxgmms2!VIDMM_GLOBAL::PageInFromFaultedList (public: long __cdecl VIDMM_GLOBAL::PageInFromFaultedList(class VIDMM_DEVICE *))



1: kd> x *!*irql*less*
fffff802`41daf7ec acpiex!PlExtpVerifyIrqlLessThanOrEqual (PlExtpVerifyIrqlLessThanOrEqual)

1: kd> db tcpip!TCPIP_MEMORY_FAILURES   --->    a constant unfortunately
fffff802`42a0d900  55 04 00 10 02 00 55 04-80 00 00 00 80 00 00 80  U.....U.........
fffff802`42a0d910  92 05 00 10 05 00 89 05-00 00 00 00 01 00 00 80  ................
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to cause a BSOD on purpose? Are you looking to find a function that handles the BSOD and do you want to call it? Why would you do that? It's really not clear to my what you want to do and why.

Comment: @ThomasWeller updated. I want the symbol of the function because it can help my analysis tool track the system crash. The function's job is to handle BSOD.

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but perhaps what you're looking for is KeBugCheck. You can also register a callback with KeRegisterBugCheckCallback.

Comment: Kernel panic ~= KeBugChec.* To initiate a crash use . crash command from within windbg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After careful examination, I have found the function. Like Luke and blabb said, the target functions are KeBugCheck/KeBugCheckEx.

First, run cmd as Administrator. Second, kill the kernel process manually in the terminal. The system will then crash and generate a minidump.

```
1: kd> p
nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak+0x94:
fffff806`73ea4c74 84db            test    bl,bl
1: kd> g
Critical process 0xFFFFB38F4D8CA080 (svchost.exe) exited
Break, or Ignore (bi)? bi
```

The call stack looks sth like this. .crash won't work and will only trigger the crash function for dbg.

```
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt!PspCatchCriticalBreak+0x10e
nt!PspTerminateAllThreads+0x15b987
nt!PspTerminateProcess+0xe0
nt!NtTerminateProcess+0x9c
nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x28
```

Comment: when you are on a bugcheck .crash will not initiate another Bugcheck  [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/forcing-a-system-crash-from-the-debugger)  .crash issues a bugcheck 0xe2  manually initiated crash